# Как ускорить регистрацию spring cloud eureka с микросервисом?

Tags: микросервисы, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, eureka

У меня есть приложение spring-cloud-eureka,соответственно один сервис у меня eureka-server, второй gateway и client.

После запуска всех сервисов, коннект между ними происходит через секунд 30-40, хотя eureka практически сразу регистрирует у себя gateway и client, но попасть через gateway в client -> gateway:port/client/controller получается только через некоторое время...

Как, например с помощью kafka, устроить быстрое связывание между собой этой структуры, именно не общение между сервисами, а взаимодействие eureka с микросервисами?